# Swift: working with asynchronous calls

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, asynchronous

The logic of my application is the following:

connect to server -> get JSON ->

if success: delete previous data from CoreData -> store it in CoreData -> Show in tableView

if failure: just take from CoreData and show in tableView

I don't know better place of running this logic than in `viewDidLoad` method.

So in mentioned method I have the following code:

```
import UIKit

class TopRatedViewController: UIViewController {

    var importedRates: NSArray = []
    var successfullyConnected: Bool = true


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //MARK: Connection to web service
        let urlString: String = "http://alma.com/get.php"

        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                self.successfullyConnected = false
            }else {
                var jsonresult = NSArray()
                do {
                    jsonresult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
                        self.importedRates = jsonresult
                } catch _ {
                    print("error loading rates")
                    self.successfullyConnected = false
                }
            }
        })

        task.resume()

        print(successfullyConnected)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I was going to check `successfullyConnected` variable after `task.resume()` but as soon as it is asynchronous call, it first checks the value and my logic is screwed up.

Does anyone know how could I change this to make it work? Maybe I should amend my initial working logic?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have a subclass of `NSManagedObject` with a name like `Rate`? Assuming you have such a class or a similar one, you should implement an asynchronous function like

`fetchRates(session: NSURLSession, url: NSURL, moc: NSManagedObjectContext, completion: ([Rate]?, ErrorType?) -> ())`

This function fetches rates from the given URL, stores them in the persistent store (deleting existing ones) and returns (possibly a copy) of the rates associated with the given moc. If the remote fetch fails, retrieve the existing rates from the persistent store.

There's a caveat with this function, though: `fetchRates` would never return an error when the remote fetch fails. IMHO, you should separate the "remote fetch" and the "local fetch" into two different functions in order to generate better error messages.

Your `viewDidLoad` can then be implemented like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let urlString: String = "http://alma.com/get.php"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)! // check for errors!!
    let moc = ... // specify the moc where the Rate objects should be associated with when returned in the completion handler
    self.fetchRates(url, session: self.session, moc: moc) { (rates, error) in
        // When we reach here, the rates array should already be saved 
        // into your Core Data persistent store.
        if let rates = rates {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                // display Core Data Objects in table view, 
                // possibly move the Rate objects into another moc, etc.
                // (Hint: consider using NSFetchedResultsController)


                // Set the "model" of the view controller (that is, the array of rates.
                self.rates = rates  // caution: rate objects will be accessed from the main thread - so, the MOC must be appropriate!

                // Force the table or collection view to reload data:
                ...

            }
        } else {
            // handle error
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Some notable hints:

Each view controller should have a "model" - which is the data displayed in its view.

The model must be accessed in the main thread only. Each time!

When rendering Core Data managed objects, the associated moc must be suitable for the main thread.

When using Core Data, you should consider using `NSFetchedResultsController` in conjunction with a table or a collection view.

Consider displaying an overlay saying "loading..." or/and placeholder data in the view when the data is not yet available (that is, a remote fetch is being executed and no previous data is available).

Answer (score 1):

As you note, you can't check `print(successfullyConnected)` after `task.resume()` because `dataTaskWithURL` runs asynchronously.

You should update Core Data and your UI here:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { 
    (data, response, error) in

    if data == nil {
        // Use Core Data
    } else {
        var jsonresult = NSArray()
        do {
            jsonresult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
            self.importedRates = jsonresult
            // Update table view on main queue
            // Update Core Data
        } catch { // You don't need the wildcard _
            print("error loading rates")
            self.successfullyConnected = false
            // This could happen because of a JSON parsing error
            // Not clear that you need to use the existing data in Core Data
        }
    }
})
```

I'm not sure you need `successfullyConnected`, but perhaps you are using it elsewhere?